Invalid block tag on line 126: 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
I want to use {% set … } but it has problem is django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 126: ‘set’, expected ‘empty’ or ‘endfor’. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
what should i do ?

html file

<div class="carousel-inner">
   {% for knowledge in knowledges %}
       {% set count = 0 %}
       {% for photo in photo01s %}
           {% if photo.category01 == knowledge %}
           {% set count = count + 1 %}
                <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="card" style="background-image: url('{{ photo.image01.url }}');"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
</div>                


models.py

class Knowledge(models.Model):
    name01 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name01

class Photo01(models.Model):
    category01 = models.ForeignKey(Knowledge, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    image01 = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    description01 = models.TextField()
    title01 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title01


views.py

def knowledge01(request):
    knowledges = Knowledge.objects.all()
    photo01s = Photo01.objects.all()

    context = {'knowledges': knowledges, 'photo01s': photo01s}
    return render(request, 'photos/knowledge01.html', context)

I have tried several ways but it does not work.

So where do you use count in the template?

You have asked same question yesterday, please refrain of opening new questions but edit it to add relevant data instead

@iklinac, yes, and the OP failed to share views and models iirc.

Don't perform "join"s in the template. Templates should implement rendering logic, not business logic, and templates are notoriously slow, and thus it would not work very efficiently.
Secondly, your template does not use count anyware, so setting this variable makes not much sense either. I assume the template has been generated by a chatbot, since chatbots often perform variable assignments in a template, and to make matters worse, "make up" template tags that do not exist.
We can prefetch the images in the view:
def knowledge01(request):
    knowledges = Knowledge.objects.prefetch_related('photo01_set')

    context = {'knowledges': knowledges}
    return render(request, 'photos/knowledge01.html', context)
<div class="carousel-inner">
   {% for knowledge in knowledges %}
       {% for photo in knowledge.photo01_set.all %}
           <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="card" style="background-image: url('{{ photo.image01.url }}');"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
</div>


Note: Specifying null=False [Django-doc] is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.



Note: Specifying blank=False [Django-doc] is not necessary: fields are by default not blank and thus are required by a form.


thanks for your help, your code works and i have a new problem.  i want to have 5 items in each carousel-item but it has only one item for each carousel-item. what should i do next ?
